# How to get the remote of a commit (faster)

Tags: git, github, version-control

My git repository has `11` remotes and `744` remote branches.
In this setup `time git branch -r --contains commit-ish` returns after `51s` on my i5-3320M.

`git branch -r --contains` being slow seems to be a known issue in the git community. That's why I don't aim to improve this time. Since I don't need such a high granularity of results, my only question/hope is maybe there is a *faster* way (let's say under `3s`) to determine the remote name(s) *only* (one/several of 11 configured in my case) a specific commit originates from?

Thanks!

Comment: For what purpose do you need to know which remote a commit came from?

Comment: Thanks for this question! I plan to incorporate the remote name (actually an alias of it) in the `(cherry picked from REMOTE commit <hash>)` message when calling `git cherry-pick -x <hash>` by means of a git hook.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this; and in fact, in a general distributed environment, this question fundamentally makes no sense.  Here's why, first wrapped in an example.

Let's posit three other programmers / players, named Alice, Bob, and Carol.  These three have Git repositories which you call remotes A, B, and C.

Bob writes some code and makes a commit.  This generates a new, unique hash ID, which by some sort of coincidence, is `b0bb0b`.  If you now obtain this commit from Bob using `git fetch B`, you will find `b0bb0b` contained in a remote-tracking branch named `refs/remotes/B/somename`.  It will *not* be in any A or C remote-tracking branch.  So far, it looks like this works.

But before you fetch from Bob, Alice fetches from Bob, and fast-forwards Bob's commit into one of Alice's branches.  Carol does the same, and then Bob realizes his commit is bad and retracts it (using `git reset`).  Now you fetch from all three remotes and look to see which remote has commit `b0bb0b`, and the answer is `refs/remotes/A/foo` and `refs/remotes/C/bar`.  Now it seems as though Alice and Carol both wrote it and Bob had nothing to do with it.

More generally, it's possible for you to pick up a commit via either `git fetch` or `git push` that is on *no* branch, e.g., is merely *tagged*.  This commit can become accessible through a branch (local or remote) later.  Or, you can pick up a commit that *is* accessible through a branch name at the time, but no longer accessible that way later, yet still permanently recorded via some other reference (including tags).

The fundamental problem here is that branch names are not only mutable, they are *arbitrarily* mutable.  Your remote-tracking branch names merely remember a (single) commit hash they got from some remote repository.  As a side effect, those names make sure that any objects (commits, trees, and blobs) *reachable from* their hash ID do not expire and thus will not be deleted by `git gc`.

On the other hand, the commits themselves are wholly *im*mutable.  This means that the commit message cannot be changed, nor the tree ID in that commit, nor any of its parent IDs.  If you can trust the hash itself to be sufficiently strong, crytographically speaking, you can use this to trust any of the parent commits as well.  This is how and why GPG-signing an *annotated tag* becomes sufficient to protect not only the tag itself, but also the commit the tag points-to, and all previous commits as well.  (You can also GPG-sign the commit directly but this seems to cause more pain than pleasure, in the end: for the Git project itself, for instance, the authors only GPG-sign release tags.)

You can, of course, argue that you will never rewind / rewrite branch names like this, nor allow the various players to collude—wittingly or no—to avoid responsibility / blame for any particular commit.  But in the end, this question really does seem to be about *traceability:* where did commit X come from?  And this is what GPG signatures are for: you GPG-sign commit X, or a tag pointing to commit X, to indicate that you, the GPG-signer, have placed a stamp of approval upon X (and hence all earlier commits as well).  That's probably a better way to tackle this problem.  But it will still be slow.

#### A faster, albeit much less powerful yet still hard to code, alternative

Whether or not this is your goal, you *can* implement a faster version of tracing "where a commit first came from" *if* you control all the points at which a commit enters the repository, i.e., if you use `git fetch` yourself to obtain commits, and/or use a `pre-receive` hook.  The way this works is to enumerate, at the time you acquire new commit objects, all "previously reachable" commit objects (before updating references), then all "newly reachable" commit objects (after updating references).  This is a bit tricky as you must be sure that references do not change during your enumeration process.  In other words, you probably want a lock, external to Git.  (You will probably want this anyway as you will want an atomic update operation for your database.)

In other words, you would, in effect, run `git rev-list --all` before the reference updates, and then again afterward.  The output of each is the set of all reachable commits.  Commits that go from reachable to unreachable—i.e., are in the first set but not the second—were *deleted* by the update, and commits that go from unreachable to reachable were *added* by the update.

Note that the same commit hash can become unreachable (it's retracted as premature) and then later reachable again (it's now deemed mature, despite being entirely unchanged), and the identity of its offerer—though not the identity of author or committer, since those are part of the commit object and hence participate in the hash—may change during that period.  It's up to you to decide what, if anything, you wish to do about *that*.

Meanwhile, you would keep a separate database (or key/value store) of <commit-ID, point-at-which-introduced / any additional data> tuples.  It's up to you to decide how to update this (do you track *every* add and delete, or only the *first* add?).  If you are only interested in "first additions" and do not need to record deletions, you can speed up the `git rev-list`s quite a bit: instead of running `git rev-list --all` each time, your task becomes "turn all refs into hash IDs, then run `git rev-list <all the new hash IDs> --not <all the old hash IDs>`" to find all commits—if any—newly introduced by the new hash IDs.

Note that you must do this with the IDs themselves, not just the reference names, since you either have not yet changed the name-to-ID mappings inside the Git repository (so that the new IDs are merely *proposed*), or you *have* changed them (so that the old IDs are no longer available).  If you do this based on *proposed* updates, be sure the updates actually go through successfully before committing your database changes and releasing your database lock.  Consider also any complications introduced if some updates succeed and others fail, which is allowed by, e.g., the `update` hook if any.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort put in answering my question. However, I feel like your point of view tends to be very generic (looking from the sky), whilst my problem is something taken from developer's everyday headaches. Particularly, I am integrating a SW release coming from several suppliers. Each supplier has its own remote/repo. For certain reasons, I can't merge or `rebase --onto` these updates locally. The only solution is to cherry pick them. What I want is just to specify the remote in the `cherry picked from` message. I basically try to automate it in the `prepare-commit-msg` hook

Comment: However, waiting for nearly one minute to get the list of remotes containing one commit is just insane.

Comment: `But in the end, this question really does seem to be about traceability: where did commit X come from?` Yes! You got it right! I actually know right from the beginning where the commit comes from. I am just angry that git needs to think so much about it!

Comment: @EugeniuRosca: I like to try to view the problem from all positions, if possible. :-) The thing is, if you know in advance what label to put on it, pass that through to your cherry-pick operation. (E.g., if you are automatically editing the commit message through a scripted `$GIT_EDITOR`, provide your own env variable, e.g., `$SOURCE`, and have your script use `$SOURCE` rather than running `git branch --contains`.)

Comment: This is slightly better than `cherry-pick -x --edit` (then copy paste into editor), but still not automated. My understanding is that git calculates internally the merge-base of given commit with every branch on every remote and compares the result, each time, with the commit itself. If there is a match, the the commit is considered `contained` in the branch. `git branch --contains` seems to be slow because `merge-base` is an expensive operation.

Comment: According to what other people say, `git branch --contains` seems to be linear with the number of branches. What this basically means is that git doesn't learn anything when calculating various merge-bases. It just runs the same algorithm in a loop, probably traversing the same paths in the history again and again. I hope somebody can improve it.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca: `--contains` doesn't compute merge bases, just "is parent" relationships: branch label *X* "contains" commit *C* if and only if *C* is an ancestor of the commit to which *X* resolves. Git currently does a linear scan for each branch name. What you would need to do, to speed this up, is to mark (in memory) each commit during each scan as "definitely IS parent", "definitely IS NOT parent", or (initially) "unmarked", so that subsequent scans can terminate upon reaching any marked commit. However, this would slow down `git branch --contains` if there is only one branch being tested.